# How to mock ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, observablecollection

I have the following:

```
class foo : ObservableCollection<Int32>
{
  //Stuff
}


[Test]
public void test()
{
  var foo = Mock.Of<foo>();
  int count = 0;
  Mock.Get(foo).Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<Int32>())).Callback(() => count++);
  Mock.Get(foo).Setup(x => x.Count).Returns(() => count);
  //Do Stuff
}
```

However, `Add` and `Count` and especially the `indexer[]` are not overrideable. Is my only recourse, to create `Addfoo` that calls `Add` in my foo class, etc?

Comment: Why would you want to mock this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you should mock such base types as `List`, `ObservableCollection`, or `DateTime` (even if it was possible). They are reliable and unlikely to change. Simply use `ObservableCollection` in your test instead of trying to re-implement it's count-increasing functionality. You always can do state-based verification:

```
var items = new ObservableCollection<int>();
// Do stuff
Assert.That(items.Count, Is.EqualTo(5));
```

If you are using your custom type `Foo` which is inherited from `ObservableCollection<Int32>` then you can also implement some `IFoo` interface which will be easy to mock:

```
public class Foo : ObservableCollection<Int32>, IFoo
```

Comment: Yah, I need to look deeper at what is actually wanted for the test. It is a coworker's test and I forgot the golden rule to question the original assumption. That might be the problem in itself

Comment: Since there is functionality in foo, we just set `CallBase = true` on the mock. So, we don't have to worry about overriding Add, Count, etc. But, can override the custom stuff